# Set default font for Output

Tags: fonts

Is it possible to set the font family to Arial for axes, legends and labels globally?

I found out about

```
SetOptions[
  Legending`GridLegend, 
  Legending`LegendContainer -> (Framed@ Append[#, FontFamily -> "Arial"] &)
];
```

for legends, but now I am trying to set the axis labels.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to `AxesStyle` etc. which can be set for specific functions such as `Plot` with e.g. `SetOptions[Plot, ...]` there are more global FrontEnd settings by Box type.  These are accessible in the Option Inspector:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From here we can set options that apply to multiple plot functions, and in fact all `Graphics` objects that do not override the defaults. You can see in the screen shot that there are options for a variety of FrontEnd graphics Box types, and categories for "Graphics3D" and "Specific" Box Options as well.

You can also do this by command, e.g.:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
  GraphicsBoxOptions -> {AxesStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial"]}
]
```

Change `$FrontEndSession` to `$FrontEnd` to make the style persistent.

Comment: p.s. see also the documentation for [`DefaultAxesStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DefaultAxesStyle.html), and other symbols in `Names["Default*Style"]`.

Answer (score 6):

Use `AxesStyle` with `Directive`

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Red, 15, FontFamily -> "Arial"]]
```

To set things globally, use `SetOptions`

```
 SetOptions[Plot, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Red, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, FontFamily -> "Arial"]];

Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLabel -> "my plot",AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]