# How do I set the fonts for Input and Output in my stylesheet?

Tags: output-formatting, stylesheet

I'd like to change the font that *Mathematica* uses for output by setting the font of the corresponding style in my stylesheet, but simply overriding the default `Output` style with

```
Cell[StyleData["Output"],FontFamily->"Open Sans",FontSize->12]
```

seems to have no effect.

Is there a way to do this that I'm missing? Is the style used for output something different?

---

Note that this is not a duplicate of "[Set default font for Output](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10776/37)", despite the title.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: If I understand that, I've got to change `StandardForm`, but that changes both `Input` and `Output`. Is there no way to change just `Output`? (And what's the `Output` style for if it has no effect on output?)

Comment: I just read those answers and I too am dissatisfied with them.  There are some surprising limitations of the system ("Undo" cough) but this doesn't appear to be one of them as you can select an Output cell and change the font family.  I don't know why it is set up this way.

Comment: The earlier question did not concern output styles. The reason you can't do this easily is because `Core.nb` defines `DefaultFormatType -> DefaultOutputFormatType` for the output style and this is the `StandardForm`. You can set `DefaultFormatType` to some other *Form and change that instead, because modifying `StandardForm` will also change the input sytle.

Comment: @rm-rf I'm sorry, I now realize that is true.  I know I have seen the recommendation/instruction to change `StandardForm` to effect change in `"Output"` (and `"Input"`) before; that is what I am dissatisfied with.  Sorry for unintentionally disparaging your answer!

Comment: @rax I notice that you did not Accept an answer to this question.  Did you find that the method I suggested has problems or limitations?  Is there an issue I can attempt to address to improve my answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Honestly, I'm not sure now. It's been a while (and with all the changes in version 10, who knows!). I expect if I didn't accept it pretty quickly, it didn't work for me at the time, or there were some issues I needed to test further. I'll have a look next time I confront *Mathematica* (kind of on hold since 10 [broke nearly all my notebooks](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54570/37)).

Answer (score 8):

After a bit of style sheet spelunking I believe I have a solution.

One reads in `Core.nb` under the **FormatType Styles** section:

> The cells below define styles that are mixed in with the styles of most cells.  If a cell's FormatType matches the name of one of the styles defined below, then that style is applied between the cell's style and its own options. This is particularly true of Input and Output.

From this it becomes clear why the styles one creates for `Input` and `Output` are not respected.  That leads me to my proposed method.  The template for the private style sheet is as follows:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Key in the options for the top cell, placed *above* the **base definitions** cell, is:

```
FontFamily -> Inherited
```

However one should start with the original definition from `Core.nb` and add/change `FontFamily -> Inherited` or important settings such as [`InputAutoReplacements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAutoReplacements.html) will be lost.  You can use this code to generate the complete Cell needed:

```
CellPrint @ Cell[StyleData["StandardForm"], ##] & @@
  (CurrentValue[{"StyleDefinitions", "StandardForm"}] /.
     (FontFamily -> _) :> (FontFamily -> Inherited))
```

(Evaluate this in a standard Notebook, then copy and paste the result at the very top of the Style Sheet.)

This changes the way that the `"Input"` and `"Output"` styles work.  Now you create font style cells for both, e.g.:

```
Cell[StyleData["Input"],
 FontFamily -> "Courier"
]

Cell[StyleData["Output"],
 FontFamily -> "Trajan Pro"
]
```

And *prestidigitonium!*

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: To make this robust it will at least be necessary to consider any other styles that rely on StandardForm and also the different Screen and Printing Environments.

Comment: +1 brilliant. Had forgotten about the ordering of cells in stylesheets.

Comment: **Addendum**: this doesn't operate with quite the mechanism that I first thought, but I believe it still works.  However, the content of the first cell should be the entire definition for `"StandardForm"` from `Core.nb` *except* for the `FontFamily` line, rather than the stub shown in this answer.  I'll revisit this tomorrow and do some more testing, then update the post.

Comment: I had only done some toy testing and didn't notice any issues with it. What led you to write the addendum?

Comment: @Mike on my system I'm losing some of the proper formatting of e.g. Input cells with the simple code shown in the post. (Put another way, not only is the font reset but so is everything else.)  I can't rule out that I've just made a mistake but I'm too sleepy to work through it now.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that on my system (8.0.4, mac 10.6.8) but did not exactly carry out exhaustive testing -- but toy tests were fine. IMO this is definitely a better approach than my answer.

Comment: Thanks! this resolved my problem.

Comment: @x7x7 I'm glad this worked for you, and thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if there is a straight forward way but here is one way that works.

Edit the private styles of your notebook as per these grabs:

[image]

[image]

And now your output is Comic Sans :)

[image]

You can also:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 CommonDefaultFormatTypes -> {"Output" -> OutputForm}]
```

but you still need to make your changes to the `OutputForm` style.

Comment: +1 for `CommonDefaultFormatTypes` which I either haven't learned or forgot, but I recommend you use a custom style e.g. `"MyOutput"` instead of `OutputForm` or you get the ugly 2D text formatting.

Comment: -1 for Comic Sans, +2 for a good solution. :)

Comment: Hm... I see that my recommendation is not valid.  That makes this answer significantly less useful IMHO unless there is another work-around to avoid the text-terminal 2D output.

Comment: @rcollyer I'm not sure it's really a solution (yet?); I don't think people want to have to use `OutputForm` -- at least *I* don't.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard correct me if I'm wrong, isn't `OutputForm` the default for output cells?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard AFAIK `CommonDefaultFormatTypes` will only accept built in *Form, i.e. myOutputForm will lead to an error.

Comment: @rcollyer no, the default is `StandardForm`; `OutputForm` is the text-terminal style.  See the first example [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OutputForm.html).  Mike, yes that's right, but I'm working on another method.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this question comes up in forums every now and then and I don't think I have ever seen a satisfactory answer. A (reasonably) straight forward solution would be to modify `StandardForm` but the OP wants to keep the `Output` appearance different to `Input`.

Comment: Mike, please review my answer.  You have more experience with these things than I do; is this going to work?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard excellent answer -- belongs in FAQ

Comment: @Mr.Wizard kind of embarrassed by my answer now after reading yours :)

Comment: This doesn't work with graphics: I get just `- Graphics -` as output for all plots, etc — in Comic Sans though!