# Is it possible to change the fontsize when printing a notebook in the working environment?

Tags: fonts, printing, syntax-highlighting

I want to print a notebook that owns syntax color,I use the [Szabolcs's method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/451/saving-a-notebook-as-pdf-preserving-syntax-highlighting/456#456)

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

Then I can achieve a PDF file shown as below:

[image: Working Environment]

However,when I change the `PrintingStyleEnvironment to "Printout"`

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Printout"]
```

[image: Printout Environment]

I feel the fontsize in the `Working Environment` is more large than `Printout Environment`.

So my question is:

**How to make the fontsize in `Working Environment` be same with `Printout Environment`.**

**I feel the fontsize in `Printout Environment` is very suitable.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48846/280) answer.  Add the following to the private style sheet:

```
Cell[StyleData[All, "Working"],
 Magnification -> 0.8
]
```

Adjust the `Magnification` setting according your needs.

Answer (score 4):

For those like me who were confused even after reading Alexey Popkov's answer, let me provide more detail:

Click Format -> Edit stylesheet

A window will open that says "Private stylesheet for your_notebook's_name"

Copy-paste the following code below where it says "local definitions for style all: all"

```
Cell[StyleData[All, "Working"], Magnification -> 0.8]
```

A dialog box will appear that says "the text you are pasting corresponds to a cell expression..." Click YES

The text it adds now reads "local definitions for all styles in style environment 'working'". Note that it doesn't say anything about magnification anymore. THIS IS NORMAL. Close the window and your changes have been saved. Print your PDF (in "working" printing environment) and it works.