# Font size for help drop down menu in input cell

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization

Consider:

[image]

Where do I go and how do I increase the `FontSize` in this drop down menu to make it more easy to read?

Answer (score 3):

Details of the solution and additional comments may be found in: [How to change the default font for all cells in all notebooks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100273/5478)

- got to menu `Format / Edit Stylesheet`
- copy to the opened stylesheet cells from `Core.nb` (no all of them, only selected on a picture below)

(*the Core.nb is in $InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Stylesheets*)

> [image]

- edit `"CodeAssistCompletion"` and `"CodeAssistUsage"`, the rest will inherit it.

> [image]

Comment: Where do I get core.nb. And when you say edit "CodeAssistCompletion" what does that mean? Edit what? Thanks.

Comment: @David sorry for confusion, take a look at edits I've made. If anything is not clear, tell me.