# How set input font globally?

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to change input font in default.nb, but font font not changed, changed only font size. I'm also try set StandartForm style, but nothing happens. In preferences/Evaluation style of newly typed cells set correct. 
For output i find option in option inspector, but for input i'm dont find this option. 
How else i can set input font globally?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: An equivalent question for Output font: [(14536)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14536/121)

Comment: I asked this same question of Wolfram a very long time ago, so long I've lost the response and possible that the answer is no longer valid.  The gist of the answer was that the input font is 'special' in someway and changing it may break some of the parsing process so it cannot (or cannot easily) be changed.

Comment: @Ymareth Not easily is true, but it can be changed.  See my recently updated answer to the Q&A linked above.  Ivan, after testing my revised answer in the current release of *Mathematica* I am closing this question as "already answered" as my posts equally addresses both Input and Output styles.

Comment: Mr.Wizard, not found that question, solution from him worked for me, thanks!