# How to restore the font size and other options to default Globally

Tags: front-end, formatting

I have messed up  the font size globally.
I was playing with SetOptions and I think I have accidentally changed the font setting of the FronEnd setting globally as can be seen here.

[image]

I tried to uninstall Mathematical and instal it again but that did not help.
how can I reset the font size to default.

Comment: You may want to try this: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3274. I haven't tried it since I obviously don't want to lose my MMA settings. If it works, credits to @halirutan for pointing me to it in the chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you merely set to some `$FrontEnd` options unintentionally.  If you can figure out what these options are you can reset them by clicking the **X** next to the field in the Option Inspector:

[image]

You can also select **as text** rather than **by category** to see a list of all the options that have been changed from the default (manually or otherwise).

Comment: I was trying to understand your answer here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14536/how-do-i-set-the-font-for-output-in-my-stylesheet  and here : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10776/set-default-font-for-output but then every thing messed up.

Comment: @Algohi Sorry. :-(  Do I understand correctly that you were editing Style Sheets?

Comment: I was trying to change the font globally because I had complicated graphic so that I do not need to manually style the fonts of everything in the graph. but then I released that I did some thing wrong which messed up the font globally.

Comment: @Algohi Do you recall what exactly you were doing?  Of course you don't know what went wrong, but it would help to know in what manner it happened.  Were you editing style sheets?  Using `SetOptions`?  Something else?

Comment: yes I was doing some thing one style. some thing like this SetOptions[Plot, PlotStyle -> Style[FontSize -> [20]]]; but I can't remember what exactly I did.

Comment: this is the answer to my question   SetOptions[$FrontEnd, FontSize -> 12]. how can I get the Options fro Global Preferences window you showed above?

Comment: @Algohi I'm glad you were able to resolve that problem.  Incidentally (I believe) that setting could have been reset as described in my answer above.  The Option Inspector can be opened from the command in the **Format** menu of the menu bar, or Ctrl+Shift+O in Windows.  Be sure to select **Global Preferences** and **by category**.  Then type `FontSize` into the **Lookup:** field and it should take you right to that setting.  Or you can navigate to it using the tree view in the left pane.

Comment: waw, you answer was the perfect one. I should have tried it before but I did not know how to get same window you provided.